# Subview covers up first row of UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uiview, ipad, subviews

Among other objects, I currently have a UITableView with a UIView subview.  The height of the UIView subview is set to 0, by default in Interface Builder.

When I update the height of the UIView subview programmatically, it covers up the first row of the UITableView.  I cannot adjust the y-position of the frame of the UITableView because it moves both the UITableView and the UIView subview.

Is there a way to avoid having the UIView subview cover the row of the UITableView?

Comment: It's very hard to predict without code.So, please try to put some code snippet over here!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `tableHeaderView` property of `UITableView` for this.  Setting this property to be an empty view may solve your problem.

Comment: +1 I looked everywhere for the answer, and this really helped. Before, I was trying to change the `contentInset` and had to `scrollRectToVisible`, which caused unwanted "features". It wasn't until I changed to use this code that I was perfectly happy with the results.